# LibreCAD fails to export .dxf as .pdf

Tags: pdf

When I convert a .dxf to .pdf by 'exporting as' it creates a blank pdf file.  ?

Comment: This link suggests you first need to save the file and then export as pdf. https://forum.librecad.org/PDF-Exporting-Issues-td5712825.html#a5712949

Comment: Please edit your question to sh whicht version of LibreCAD you have

Comment: I'm having the same issue in LibreCAD 2.1.3 via Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that 'export as .pdf' works when using Metric paper sizes.

I drew on Arch C 18" x 24"

I set paper size on Current Drawing Prefeences to Custom, entered 18, 24.

Export as .pdf then functioned properly.